# Marketo Calendar Invite Link CSS Styling

Tags: html, css, email, marketo

I'm having problem styling the Calendar Invite link with CSS in an HTML email. This is the output of final HTML email:

```html
<td class="textStyle" colspan="2" align="left" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; font-family: 'avenir', Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333333;"><a class="blueLink" style="font-size: 
16px; line-height: 22px; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #0088CC; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'avenir', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal;"></a><a href="http://example.com+Webinar+.ics">Click here</a> to add the event to your calendar.</td>
```

As you see Marketo will automatically insert an entire a tag with the ics and I'm not able to style it in the HTML email. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the link text of the ICS token in a span to add the appropriate styling to your link.